# Rails query works then creates an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a query to retrieve all the spots (times) available on a given date.

```
@takenspots = Spot.joins(:reservations).where('reservations.date = ?', params[:date])
        if @takenspots.any?
          @availablespots = Spot.where('id != ?', @takenspots.map)
```

I use @availablespots to populate a select_list.

I have 4 different spots per day and the query works only 2 times. (2/4 spots)

If a try to book a day where i have 2 spots taken out of 4, it says:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT "spots".* FROM "spots"  WHERE (id != 1,2)
```

But I can't understand why it works for the first 2 spots and not the 2 remaining...
Someone got an idea ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why this works actually, but it does, so this might help someone:

```
@availablespots = Spot.where('id not in (?)',@takenspots.map(&:id))
```

Comment: The OP's question was *"I can't understand why it works for the first 2 spots and not the 2 remaining... Someone got an idea"*. So your answer should explain why things did not work as expected.

Comment: I have no idea why it works actually, but now it does. So I didn't pin that as THE answer, but it might help someone.